# How to update substring in pandas dataframe column of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe ('sp500news') which looks like the following:

```
date_publish  \
79944   2007-01-29 19:08:35   
181781  2007-12-14 19:39:06   
213175  2008-01-22 11:17:19   
93554   2008-01-22 18:52:56   
  ...

title  
 79944   Microsoft Vista corporate sales go very well                                            
 181781  Williams No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church                                      
 213175  CSX quarterly profit rises                                                              
 93554   Citigroup says 30 bln capital helps exceed target                                       
    ...
```

I am trying to update each company name with its corresponding ticker from a the 'symbol' column of df ('constituents') which looks like:

```
Symbol  Name    Sector
0   MMM 3M  Industrials
1   AOS A.O. Smith  Industrials
2   ABT Abbott  Health Care
3   ABBV    AbbVie  Health Care
...
116  C      Citigroup    Financials       
...
```

I've already tried:

```
for item in sp500news['title']:
    for word in item:
        if word in constituents['Name']:
            indx = constituents['Name'].index(word)
            str.replace(word, constituents['Symbol'][indx])
```

Comment: How do you want your output to look like..

Comment: column 'title' from sp500 news, all company names replaced by ticker values (from 'symbol' column in 'constituents')

Comment: Where are your ticker values?

Comment: 'symbol' column of df 'constituents'

Comment: How do I know a symbol is corresponding to which company name? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I guess by direct match @mohitmotwani. Although it is indeed very clear, specially as there are no matches in the input provided

Comment: the columns of `constituents` are as follows: `Symbol` (ticker) `Name` (company name. I will add extra data

Comment: For example, replace 'Citigroup' with 'C'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['Citigroup says 30 bln capital helps exceed target',
                             'Williams No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church',
                             'Microsoft Vista corporate sales go very well']})

constituents = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['MMM', 'C', 'MCR', 'WLM'],
                             'name': ['3M', 'Citigroup', 'Microsoft', 'Williams']})

for name, symbol in zip(constituents['name'], constituents['symbol']):
    df['title'] = df['title'].str.replace(name, symbol)
```

Output

```
                                           title
0      C says 30 bln capital helps exceed target
1  WLM No Anglican consensus on Episcopal Church
2         MCR Vista corporate sales go very well
```

I basically just copied a few rows of your `sp500news['title]` and made up some of `constituents['Name']` just to demonstrate the transformation. Essentially, I am accessing the string method object of the `pd.Series` object of column `title` from `sp500news`, so then I can apply `replace` to it when it finds the matching company name.

Comment: Avoid using for loops on a dataframe. For loops are slow

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Here are the dummy dataframes which represent your data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': ['MV', 'AOS','ABT'],
                  'Name': ['Microsoft Vista', 'A.0.', 'Abbot']})
df1
  Symbol    Name
0   MV  Microsoft Vista
1   AOS A.0.
2   ABT Abbot
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'title': [79944, 181781, 213175],
                   'comment': ['Microsoft Vista corporate sales go very well',
                              'Abbot consensus on Episcopal Church',
                              'A.O. says 30 bln captial helps exceed target']})

    title   comment
0   79944   Microsoft Vista corporate sales go very well
1   181781  Abbot consensus on Episcopal Church
2   213175  A.O. says 30 bln captial helps exceed target
```

Make a dictionary of values mapping names to their respective symbols

```
rep = dict(zip(df1.Name,df1.Symbol))
rep

{'Microsoft Vista': 'MV', 'A.0.': 'AOS', 'Abbot': 'ABT'}
```

Replace them using the [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) method

```
df2['comment'] = df2['comment'].replace(rep, regex = True)
df2
   title    comment
0   79944   MV corporate sales go very well
1   181781  ABT consensus on Episcopal Church
2   213175  A.O. says 30 bln captial helps exceed target
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What you want to put in a function? What exactly do you mean by an object?